# Why does my timeout is exceeded?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

I'm developing an API with Node.js and Express and i'm using Mocha and Supertest to write unit tests. I have a BIG file of tests which test every route with almost random parameters to see if my error handling works well.

Everything was great until, for no reason, my requests are starting to timeout.

This is more or less my code :

```
var supertest = require("supertest");
var should = require("should");

var server = supertest.agent("http://localhost:3000");

function requestAuth(url, type, auth, params, callback) {
  if (params == null) {
    server[type](url)
    .type('form')
    .auth(auth.email, auth.password)
    .expect("Content-type",/json/)
    .expect(200)
    .end(callback);
  }
  else {
    server[type](url)
    .send(params)
    .auth(auth.email, auth.password)
    .type('form')
    .expect("Content-type",/json/)
    .expect(200)
    .end(callback);
  }
}

describe('Testing route 1', function() {
  describe('Testing param 1 error handling', function() {
    it('should return error 1', function(done) {
      requestAuth(route1, "post", {email: email, password: password}, {param1: "blahblahblah"}, 
      function(err, res) {
        res.body.should.have.property('error');
        done();
      });
    });
    it('should return error 2', function(done) {
      requestAuth(route1, "post", {email: email, password: password}, {param1: "blahblahblah"}, 
      function(err, res) {
        res.body.should.have.property('error');
        done();
      });
    });
    // etc
  });
  describe('Testing param 2 error handling', function() {
    it('should return error 3', function(done) {
      requestAuth(route1, "post", {email: email, password: password}, {param1: "blahblahblah"}, 
      function(err, res) {
        res.body.should.have.property('error');
        done();
      });
    });
    it('should return error 4', function(done) {
      requestAuth(route1, "post", {email: email, password: password}, {param1: "blahblahblah"}, 
      function(err, res) {
        res.body.should.have.property('error');
        done();
      });
    });
    // etc
  });
  //etc
});

describe('Testing route 2', function() {
  //etc
});
```

Except that i have of LOT of tests.
At some point, let say that when i'm testing route 8, every tests starts to fail with the following message :

```
  12) Route 8 Testing Param 1 error handling should return error 1:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
      at null.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/mocha/lib/runnable.js:139:19)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

I really don't get it. Everything worked well since then, done is called at the end of every request, should be good. Nothing happens on the server side even though routes are ok. This is really weird...

Also, if the route 8 tests are getting weird, and that i comment route 7 tests for example, than route 9 tests will starts to act wrong.

I think this is coming from supertest. Is it possible that it is overloaded ? How could i fix that ?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Your tests themselves have a time limit to complete your actions. This means that if the resource isn't set up and available in those two seconds, or if the test completes after two seconds it will fail. Use `this.timeout = [milliseconds]` as the first line of the failing test to extend the timeout.

[MochaJS Test Level Timeouts](http://mochajs.org/#test-level)

Comment: Yeah, I know this. My request doesn't take more than 2 seconds, it doesnt even reach the API.

Comment: Have you tried moving your server initialization into a before statement for each of your larger suites? This may be your asynchronous calls acting exactly as they expect, and only causing you weirdness because the server is being torn down before all requests complete.

Comment: This is a little difficult to unravel given it's dependent on number of tests. It sounds like an async issue, and Express definitely shouldn't be failing to respond unless it's just not running.

Comment: tried to re-init my server before the tests fails, it still fail. this is incomprehensible.

Comment: Ok, found the problem... Nothing to do with supertest or express, but mysql. I forgot to release a connection to the database so after x requests the pool could not provide more connection causing the API to wait. Silly of me.